# What's the meaning of "while the bands play" in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, metaphors

> It's all I can do to sit still while the bands play. I can’t believe Mirror Boy was in the system. I don’t know if he was when he died or not. (*The Ghost Files*, by Apryl Baker)

Who's "thinking" here is a teenager who can see ghosts. She and the kid she's talking about are foster kids. Considering one of the comments, it's probably a metaphor. But I can't quite grasp the meaning.

Comment: This really needs more context. it may be intended literally -- the person is at some sort of concert or performance. Or it may be part of a metaphor. "The band plays" and "the band plays on"  are phrases frequently used metaphorically. What is the source of the sentence, please? Please see: [Why you should cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084).

Comment: This should be closed for not quoting source.

Comment: C'mon Michael, it hasn't been that long since they asked. Give it time.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Why did you remove your answer? It was spot on.

Comment: Given that the source is now known, it seems pointless not to edit it into the question, and flat-out wrong to vote to close.

Comment: @Lambie, I kind of felt exploited that I had to 1. Find out the source of the text by doing a Google exact-text search, 2. Read the preceding chapter, as the OP presumably had already done, in which the band competition is mentioned. I felt all of this made the question severely off-topic. I still do.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an idiom or metaphor. That sentence is the start of Chapter Eighteen of the Ghost Files by April Baker. In the previous chapter (Seventeen) the narrator goes to a "rock band tournament", where a number of bands compete for a prize, and right at the end, receives some surprising information, and, as the next chapter starts, is considering it while the rock bands play.

Comment: I got the book details using a Google search using the quoted text. Some web sites are showing chapter 18 (only) as a sample; other have the whole text.